# After Effect 3D layer effects

Tags: 3d, after-effects, video-editing

I created a layer and apply saber effect on it. Then ,I duplicate the first layer but when
I converted the both layer into 3D the second layer effect disappear.

what I wanted to do with my layer - I want to rotate one layer on x-axis and another on y-axis without loosing the saber effect on both layer[image: after effect work]

Answer (score 0):

Having watched Video Copilots own tutorial again it seems like you have to use the blend mode. I.E. "Add" oder "Screen". Unfortunately there is no option to set an alpha.

Edit:
A little more accurate is to add "Set Matte" effect on the top layer in addition. In "Take Matte From Layer" use the layer itself and use "Masks". And "Use For Matte" = Luminance.

Unfortunately that kills the nice falloff which you need to tweak again with a curves effect i.e. before sending it into the "Set Matte" effect.

Sorry. It's a brute force work around. :)